What is the displacement of E$_g$ mode of SrTiO$_3$ in tetragonal phase?
In the tetragonal phase, SrTiO$_3$ belongs to the D$_{4h}$ point group and possesses two Raman-active modes with the symmetry rep of A$_{1g}$ and E$_g$. However, in most books only 7 modes (normal coordinate motions) are shown for D$_{4h}$ point group while E$_g$ mode is not included, as shown below for XeF$_4$ molecule as an example. So I am wondering if anyone can offer some help about the displacement of this mode. Thanks!


you need to provide additional information on the rep and the group.

What do you mean?

presumably the irrep has a character table, and a list of elements,  and some action on physical states.  What is the notation for irreps?  Are we talking about the symmetries of a square here?

It is a unit cell of XeF$_4$.

sorry but this is not helpful.  Right now it is extremely difficult to provide an answer because there is 0 context for your question or your notation.  A typical reader cannot learn much from the way your question is presented.  I suggest you provide some background else the question (which may be interesting) will remain closed.  What is $E_g$?  is it the identity rep?

Hi, I already edited my question and do you still think it is not clear?

not really.  You still have not defined the notation nor the representation, not even given the generators of your group.  One would need to know all this to answer; moreover this severely limits the interest of the question.  As written it is not useful to any user other than you.
